# Checking for decimal after 10 digits - substring(i,1) not working

Tags: java, android, substring

I have two problems:

1. `x.substring(i,1)` breaks in the `try/catch`
2. because of that and possibly other things, I can't get this method to work. I'm trying to have it so when the user enters a decimal, it will increase the `max length` of the `EditText`, but decrease the `max length` back to the original `max length` if the user enters a number that is too large.

   ```
   boolean tooBig = false;
   EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
   TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
   String x = txt.getText().toString(); // the String in the EditText
   String str = "didn't work";
   try
   {
       if (x.contains(".")) 
       {
           // set the max length to be 15
           if (x.length() >= 10)
           {
               // see if the decimal is contained after 10 digits
               for (int i = 10; i < x.length(); i++)
               {
                   str = x.subtring(i,1); // breaks here (test)
                   if (x.substring(i,1).equals(".")) // also breaks here
                   {
                       tooBig = true;
                   }
               }
           }

           if (tooBig)
           {
               // set text to be blank and max length to be 8
           }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
       txt.setText(str); // "didn't work"
   }
   ```

What can I do to fix this `x.substring(i,1)` problem?

Comment: I am just guessing, but your exception is `IndexOutOfBound`s right? (besides, you should always paste stacktrace cuz i dont know what kind of error you have). Thats probably because substring got 2 arguments - `String#substring(startPosition,endPosition)`. You are probably refering to javascript substring which has (startPostionon,numberOfChars) right? Well thats wrong. Change parameters in substring to the proper ones (probably x+1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to change `(i,1)` to `(i, i+1)` because in Java, the second number is your `index end point`, not "how many characters to go for", as in some other languages. You would start at `i`, and end at 1 more than `i`.

You could easily use `indexOf(".")` to solve your problem instead. Also, have an `else` statement to change the `max length` back to the original `max length` just in case the user erases the decimal.

Change your `try` to this:

```
if (x.contains(".")) 
{
    // set the max length to be 15

    if (x.indexOf(".") > 9)
    {
        txt.setText(x.substring(0,9));   
        // set length to be 9
    }
}
else
{
    // set max length back to original
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
   for (int i = 10; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        str = x.subtring(i,1); // breaks here (test)
        if (x.substring(i,1).equals(".")) // startIndex say 10 is 
          greater than 1 which is wrong.
        {
```

Your startIndex is always greater then endIndex, which is obiously wrong and would cause java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: So it would be i+1, instead of just 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (x.substring(i,1).equals(".")) // also breaks here
{
    tooBig = true;
}
```

would have to be:

```
if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("."))
{
    tooBig = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my newly changed code:

```
boolean tooBig = false;
EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
String x = txt.getText().toString(); // the String in the EditText
try
{
    if (x.contains(".")) 
    {
        // set the max length to be 15
        if (x.length() >= 10)
        {
            // see if the decimal is contained after 10 digits
            for (int i = 10; i < x.length(); i++)
            {
                if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("."))
                {
                    tooBig = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (tooBig)
        {
            // set text to be blank and max length to be 9
        }
    }
    else // no decimal
    {
        // set the max length to be 9
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {}
```